# Auto Enhancing Images

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimage, core-image

I need to use apple's auto enhance images in my code.
I'v found example that apple showed but I'm unable to make it work. I'm not actually sure what am I doing wrong.

Here is what apple recommended: [AutoEnhanceCode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_autoadjustment/ci_autoadjustmentSAVE.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH11-SW1)

Here is what I'm doing (imageFinal is UIImage that I want to enhance):

```
- (IBAction)enhance:(id)sender {
  CIImage *myImage;
  CIImage *image = [imageFinal CIImage];
  NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[[image properties]valueForKey:kCIImageProperties] forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];
  NSArray *adjustments = [myImage autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:options];
  for (CIFilter *filter in adjustments){
    [filter setValue:myImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    myImage = filter.outputImage;
}
```

}

Error that I get is:  Incompatible pointer types sending 'const CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *const') to parameter of type 'NSString *'

I really don't know how to use this kCGImagePropertyOrrientation. I just want to apply that simple enhance.

Cheers.

Comment: Please replace the image of your code with the actual code text. It will be so much easier to read and copy.

Comment: I wanted to put actual screenshot so someone can see what is being underlined. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFString is toll free bridged to NSString.  So you can just cast it (NSString *) and it will work.  However, I also ran into this little piece of incomplete example code and thought I could improve it a little...  Made an objective-c category to solve the problem, First, make sure that you include the Core Image and ImageIO frameworks in your code.

Header:

```
@interface UIImage (AutoEnhance)
- (UIImage *)autoEnhancedImage;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

@implementation UIImage (AutoEnhanced)
- (UIImage *)autoEnhancedImage
{
    CIImage *ciOriginal = self.CIImage;
    if(!ciOriginal) {
        ciOriginal = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.CGImage];
    }
    NSDictionary *options = @{ CIDetectorImageOrientation : @(self.CGImagePropertyOrientation)};
    NSArray *adjustments = [ciOriginal autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:options];
    for (CIFilter *filter in adjustments) {
        [filter setValue:ciOriginal forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        ciOriginal = filter.outputImage;
    }
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:ciOriginal fromRect:ciOriginal.extent];
    UIImage *enhancedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return enhancedImage;
}

- (CGImagePropertyOrientation)CGImagePropertyOrientation
{
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationUp;
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationUpMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationDown;
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationDownMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationLeftMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationRight;
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationRightMirrored;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            return kCGImagePropertyOrientationLeft;
    }
}
@end
```

Then to use it, just:

```
UIImage *enhancedImage = [someUIImage autoEnhancedImage];
```

Comment: It works but for some reason it never release the memory. After using this code my Memory jumps up about 50-60 mb. And Even releasing doesn't take any effect.

Comment: @Hassy - If you've got the code open, through instruments on it and check for leaks.  My guess is one of the c objects is allocated but not released.

Comment: Same here, huge leaks, even with an autoreleasepool

Comment: @Xys - Same thing I asked hassy, instrument it for leaks and edit the code when you think you've found the fix.  Only things created here are cgImage (create) which is released manually, ciOriginal and enhancedImage (alloc) which are autorelease under ARC :/

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Swift version for Auto Enhancing a UIImage

```
extension UIImage {
    func autoEnhance() -> UIImage? {
        if var ciImage = CIImage.init(image: self) {
            let adjustments = ciImage.autoAdjustmentFilters()
            for filter in adjustments {
                filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                if let outputImage = filter.outputImage {
                    ciImage = outputImage
                }
            }
            let context = CIContext.init(options: nil)
            if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) {
                let finalImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
                return finalImage
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let autoEnhanced = image.autoEnhance() // returns optional UIImage
```